# showing a grid after clicking on a button

Tags: c#, html, sql, visual-studio

well i'm trying to show a grid of records that i have in my database but whenever i click on the button nothing happens
sorry for asking such a really dumb question but i'm total noob here and i tried
to find any solution but i can't find any

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            enter something</div>
    <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
    <p>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Search" runat="server" onclick="Myp" /></p>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
  </asp:GridView>
        test<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" /></form>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

C#

```
 protected void Myp(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    //Get the button that raised the event
    //Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SearchByName", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    string name = TextBox2.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", name));
    GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   // SqlDataAdapter adapter = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    //adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.Visible = true;


}
```

Comment: start googling the following `IsPostBack, Update Panel, and javascript functions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`OnClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event as opposed to `onclick`, which is going to likely target a Javascript function (as opposed to your server-side Myp method):

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Search" runat="server" OnClick="Myp" />
```

Additionally, if your method *still* is not being called, you should try looking at the Events properties for your Button1 button to ensure that your `OnClick` event handler is configured properly and points to the `Myp` method.

Comment: thank but it's still not working and didn't really get what do you mean actually :/

Comment: Try renaming the click event handler on your button to use `OnClick` (specifically cased that way) and then check out the Properties for your specific button and look at the Events section (it should look like a lightning bolt) and ensure that the OnClick handler points to your Myp method and set it to that method if it does not).